# Mac install python without developer tools

Tags: python-3.x, xcode

I am trying to install python 3.11 without the Mac developer tools, which will give me python3.9. But when I used the vscode to open a python file, the command line installer poped up and showed the following message 'the python3 command requires the command line developer tools ....'. But I can run the python3 command in the terminal successfully.

The annoying part is the pop up window. I found some suggestions about relink or rebuild the Xcode / command line tools. But in my case, there is no Xcode path. Please let me know if there is a way to configure the path correctly.

Thank you,

I checked the link of python3 in /usr/bin
I install the python directly from the http://python.org

Answer (score 0):

Do you use `Homebrew` in your terminal?

You can try to run `brew link --overwrite --dry-run python@3.11` in your terminal to see if you need to do an update for your env path. If you do need it, the terminal will give you suggestions to relink, ex.  `brew link --overwrite python@3.11` or `rm '/usr/local/bin/2to3-3.11'`

---

I also had an issue when installing python3.11 through `Homebrew` in my terminal, it said I must use `xcode-select --install` to install python3.11.

So later on, I followed this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dtLXDuzK4kg&ab_channel=ROHITTECH) step by step, and now it works. Whenever I check `python3 --version`, it returns `Python 3.11.1`. It also allows me to install another library that depends on python3.11.

Maybe it is worth checking the current version in your terminal and seeing if need to install again the package.

Comment: I think the Mac checks the ENV variable such as python3. So it can not go through it.